# Права samba на удаление

Tags: samba, linux

Есть директория samba, в которую кладутся сканы с МФУ. Надо, чтобы пользователи могли удалять свои сканы, но не могли создавать там файлы (иначе всякая вирусня захламит директорию).

Как это реализовать? Удаление для всех, Запись - никому.

Comment: @Keir, Вы уверены, что:

    Удаление для всех, Запись - никому.

Каким образом (если это даже реализовать) сканы **пользователей** 
вообще появляются в этом оглавлении ? Какие у них права, владелец, группа ?

--

Вообще-то вопрос интересный, так сказать *Challenge*. Я почти на 100% уверен, что стандартными средствами не решается. 

Т.е. исходники Вам в руки.

Comment: Может запретить создавать файлы с определёнными расширениями (*.exe, *.dll)?
Ещё можно запретить файлы, содержимое которых начинается на MZ.

Comment: @sercxjo, а как **средствами Samba** можно реагировать на расширения ?

Наверное, я просто отстал от жизни.

Comment: @avp, можно через vfs, как антивирусы прикручивают

Answer (score 1):

как верно подсказывают в комментариях, встроенных средств для подобного поведения — нет.

надо действовать «в обход».

например, можно воспользоваться механизмом [*inotify*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

в пакете [inotify-tools](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/inotify-tools), входящем, вероятно, во все популярные дистрибутивы, есть программа *inotifywait*, которой и можно воспользоваться для данного случая.

вот пример скрипта, который в бесконечном цикле будет отслеживать появление файлов/каталогов, и, если они не соответствуют какому-нибудь критерию, удалять их. в данном примере используется признак «принадлежность группе», но это несложно изменить, чтобы адаптировать к действиям той программы, которой разрешено создавать файлы/каталоги в отслеживаемом каталоге.

```
#!/bin/bash

d=/путь/к/отслеживаемому/каталогу
g=имя_группы

while true; do
  r=$(inotifywait -re create --format '%w%f' $d 2>/dev/null)
  #echo $r
  if [ -n "$r" ]; then
    gr=$(stat --printf='%G' "$r")
    if [ "$gr" != "$g" ]; then
      rm -rf "$r" 
    fi
  fi
done
```