# Как отслеживать изменения прав доступа в поддереве указанного каталога?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, shell

Мне нужно с помощью shell-скрипта отслеживать изменения прав доступа в поддереве указанного каталога. Не знаю как реализовать сам перебор файлов с отслеживанием.

То-есть при вызове скрипта ему нужно передать путь к директории, в которой скрипт будет отслеживать изменения прав доступа с определенным интервалом, и выводить измененные файлы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Права samba на удаление](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/126981/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0-samba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: Возможно вам поможет inotify - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify