# Как перехватывать запись файла от чужого приложения?

Tags: linux

В общем есть приложение, которое не дает возможность конфигурации папки, в которую оно записывает файлы и я хотел бы перехватывать запись/чтение файлов с определенным расширением и перенаправлять их в другую папку.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542647/178576

Answer (score 2):

Я предложил бы в таком случае воспользоваться симлинком на конкретный файл или директорию

Comment: дополните ответ примером или ссылкой на более подробное решение

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно непонятный вопрос, с моей точки зрения.

1. Что такое "конфигурация папки" ? Это вообще - про что ?!
2. Как это приложение "не даёт возможность" ? Оно что делает с этой папкой?
3. Что означает "перехватить запись" ? Вы желаете УЗНАТЬ о факте записи, или Вы желаете ПЕРЕНАПРАВИТЬ ввод/вывод ?

Comment: Да все просто :) Приложение у него пишет файлы в определенную папку, жестко прошитую в самом приложении. Человеку хочется, чтобы он писал в другое место, но настройки приложения (если таковые вообще есть) это не позволяют. Вот он и спрашивает, каким образом можно заставить это приложение выполнять запись не туда, куда хочется приложению, а куда хочется ему... Другое дело, что изложено это не очень внятно, но тут уж кого как русскому в школе учили :)

Comment: Абсолютно согласен с @xboborx - сделайте симлинк и будет Вам счастье! :-)

Comment: Теоретически мне подходит inotify, как указали в комментариях под постом. С ним и буду экспериментировать.